# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined on Chrome

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```html
<form name="mousemove">
  <input type="text" name="mousex" /> mouse x: <br>
  <input type="text" name="mousey" /> mouse y: <br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mie = (navigator.appname == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false;
  if (!mie) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSDOWN);
  }

  document.onmousemove = mousePos();
  document.onmousedown = mouseClicked();
  var mousec = 0;
  var moused = 0;
  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;

  function mousePos(e) {
    if (!mie) {
      mouseX = e.pageX;
      mouseY = e.pageY;
      //not working
    } else {
      mouseX = event.clentX + document.body.scrolLeft;
      mouseY = event.clentY + document.body.scrolTop;
    }
    document.mousemove.mousex.value = mouseX;
    document.mousemove.mousey.value = mouseY;
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

I want that "mousex" will show the x line coordinates and "mousey" will show the y line coordinates. For some reason I get an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined. I look all over stackoverflow but I coudn't find something like this.

Cheers

Comment: Also, don't use ternary operator for `mie` variable. The type of the return of your expression, with `==` operator, already is a boolean. `var mie = navigator.appname == "Microsoft Internet Explorer";` is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is that you are invoking both functions `mousePos` and `mouseClicked` instead of setting them as values to be passed on events:

```
document.onmousemove = mousePos();
document.onmousedown = mouseClicked();
```

Should be:

```
document.onmousemove = mousePos;
document.onmousedown = mouseClicked;
```